# Control Initial size of xfce4-terminal?

Tags: xterm, window, xfce

As I didn't see the option to configure start window size of xfce4's terminal program , is it configurable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/xfce4-terminal/en/) there is a `--geometry=`*geometry* option. [Geometry specifications](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/7/X/#GEOMETRY_SPECIFICATIONS_2203h) are detailed in the X manual.

The example section also shows a way to use this switch:

> `Terminal --geometry 80x40 --command mutt --tab --command mc`
>
> Opens a new terminal window with a geometry of 80 columns and 40 rows
>   and two tabs in it, where the first tab runs mutt and the second tab
>   runs mc.

So all you need is to create a launcher for the terminal and specify the `--geometry` option.